# "info" : "now locked against writes, use db.fsyncUnlock() to unlock" while mongodb backup

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3

I am trying to take backup of `mongodb` database to `s3`. I created a user `s3backupuser` with a password with `read` permission. while running the script got the following error.

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: admin
{
    "info" : "now locked against writes, use db.fsyncUnlock() to unlock",
    "seeAlso" : "http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/fsynccommand",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

[This](https://github.com/RGBboy/mongodb-s3-backup/blob/master/backup.sh) is the script I am using.